# Can't Access AWS RDS Instance after Upgrade

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

Just upgraded my MySQL RDS instance from the free-tier db.t2.micro to an db.r3.large. Same storage, same security groups, same user groups/credentials, same VPC, same endpoint name, same everything.

I was previously able to access this same instance remotely through MySQL workbench before the upgrade, and according to AWS my endpoint location has not changed.

The error message received:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blahblah.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)

I've tried restarting several times. Ensured by security group allowed inbound TCP access on port 3306 for both 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Does any one of the condition meets as described here  : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/

Comment: Add an inbound rule to security group for allowing connections from your machine ,add your IP

Comment: Can you also check if you have any firewall as well configured?

Comment: @jeetendraMandal checked these docs already - none of the conditions apply - local firewalls didn't prevent be from accessing instance before, but  I will check to ensure.

Comment: have you set  an inbound rule to security group for allowing connections from your machine ,add your IP

Comment: Set a rule specifically for MyIP, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Is "publicly accessible" enabled on the RDS instance?

Comment: can you do nslookup on blahblah.rds.amazonaws.com? That is, is the address even resolvable to public IP?

Comment: nslookup yields a "non-authoriative answer" with the ip address / alias of the instance, but still can't connect via MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to restart the MySQL workbench, not reboot the RDS.

As I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770024/1285846), the database handles have changed, but the code doesn't notice. So the  MySQL workbench is using outdated handles that are being rejected.