# Error: packet sequence number wrong after upgrading RDS instance

Tags: amazon-rds

After upgrading my RDS to a larger instance class, I started seeing *packet sequence number wrong* in my error logs.

I have 2 web servers created by the ElasticBeanstalk.

How do I got rid of the error?

Most of the literature (here and on the web in general) blame this error on multithreading, which we're not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to reboot the instances, one by one.

The safest way seemed to be from the *Health* tab of the ElasticBeanstalk; select each instance, and under *Instance Action* there's a *reboot* option.

After the reboots, the *packet sequence number wrong* error was never seen again.

It seems that the 75 seconds downtime was not long enough for the code to realize it had to (close the old and) open new database connections, and was using non-existant handles.