# Can't access RDS SqlServer after tier upgrade

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, ssms, amazon-rds

I upgraded my SQL Server RDS instance, from db.t2.medium to db.t3.xlarge yesterday. Since then, I can't connect to it from my local machine using SQL Server Management Studio, Azure Data Studio or programmatic access.

My application, which is hosted in an EC2, Windows Server, under the same network, is still able to connect to the database just fine. Didn't need to touch anything, connection string is the same.

Database:

- SQL Server Express
- Engine version: 14.00.3281.6.v1
- Multi AZ: no
- IAM auth: disabled
- Parameter group: default.sqlserver-ex-14.0
- Publicly accessible: yes
- Acceptig inbound from any protocol, anywhere (0.0.0.0/0)

I've tried connecting with the admin login, and I even reset the admin password just to make sure. Also tried:

- Rebooting my computer
- Waiting 24h in case SSMS needed time to update its handles
- Forgetting the login (I had it saved in SSMS) and reetering it

Basically, nothing has changed besides the tier upgrade, except that I can't login anymore.

The full error message is:

```
Cannot connect to XXX.YYY.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=258&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Error Number: 258
Severity: 20
State: 0

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Options Encrypt Connection and Trust Server Certificate are ON in the SSMS login dialog.

I've searched Google, the forums, saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758902/cant-access-aws-rds-instance-after-upgrade) in SO, but can't figure it out.

Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess, has the public IP changed on your instance?  It's always DNS :)

Comment: Hi Pete, I can't confirm it because I don't know what the IP was before the change. But a coworker that had never logged into that database went ahead and tried it, and he succeeded. It is like it's related to that "handles" thing mentioned in the SO question I linked, but if so, how can I clear my SSMS handles? Rebooting doesn't cut it.

Comment: I don't think the "MySQL" solution will work for SQL Server.  Are you and your coworker on the same network (internet - public IP)?  But, you did open up to 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: No, we're about 3 miles apart... but yeah, 0.0.0.0/0 is open anyways

Comment: Check Windows firewall on the server?  These are my typical hiccups with remote connections to SQL Server: https://nettrax.net/2014/09/12/checklist-to-allow-remote-connection-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ssms have a cache of server handles. I believe it has something to do with your dns cache.
may I ask you to run the following. I can refine the answer based on this.

1. `nslookup XXX.YYY.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
2. `ping XXX.YYY.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
3. `telnet XXX.YYY.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 1433`
4. `sqlcmd -U<login> -S<server>:1433 -P<password>`

from 1 or 2 if you get a public IP, try using the ipaddress:1433 to connect in ssms

3 will tell if the port is not blocked by local firewall/security groups

4 is another way to try

Comment: Hi, nslookup and ping yielded an IP. Then I tried telnet and sqlcmd with both server name and IP, no success on either. Telnet "could not open connection to the host", sqlcmd "login timeout expired". Also tried renewing my IP and flushing the DNS cache.